# Scala: methods aren't functions because of JVM limitations?

Tags: scala, functional-programming, jvm

I found it often mentioned that in Scala 2 attempts like

```
def f(x: Int): Int = x*x
val g = f // note the missing type
```

aren't possible because of "underlying limitations of the JVM how it treats methods".

```
   error: missing argument list for method f
   Unapplied methods are only converted to functions when a function type is expected.
   You can make this conversion explicit by writing `f _` or `f(_)` instead of `f`.
```

I don't see the ambiguity in `g = f`. `f` is a method with a single parameter, `f` can't be a simple call.

And while methods and function objects, defined like

```
val ff: Int => Int = x => x*x
```

in Scala aren't the same, I don't know why Scala couldn't get away with just having function objects.

So what exactly are the JVM limitations that lead to these quirks?

Comment: I don't know what the limitations may have been in older scala versions, but your example compiles without error nor warning in scala 3.3.0.

Comment: `val g: Int => Int = f` works fine in Scala 2.13.

Comment: @MartinHH I'm using Scala 2.13. So does it work in 3.30 even without the type? Of course, `val g: Int => Int = f` works in Scala 2.13.

Comment: @Amaterasu yes, without type: https://scastie.scala-lang.org/sGTy5PeWRw6U4IYh5uk06g

Comment: https://docs.scala-lang.org/tutorials/FAQ/index.html#whats-the-difference-between-methods-and-functions

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Difference between method and function in Scala](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2529184/difference-between-method-and-function-in-scala)

Answer (score 3):

> I found it often mentioned that in Scala attempts like
>
> ```scala
> def f(x: Int): Int = x*x
> val g = f
> ```
>
> aren't possible because of "underlying limitations of the JVM how it treats methods".

Uhm, it depends on what exactly you expect `g` to be?
If you want it to just a function that calls `f` then it is pretty simple to do, you just need a little bit more syntax:

```scala
// All these three work.
val g = (x: Int) => f(x)
val g = f(_)
val g: Int => Int = f
```

Creating a **function** out of a **method** automatically is called *"eta-expansion"* and is only done by the compiler when the types are known, like the third `val g` example above or in the `list.map(f)` case.

---

Now, if you expect `g` to be an alias of the **method** `f`, then that is not possible.
Because `g` is a **value** and in the language **methods** are NOT **values**.

That may be due **JVM** limitations but ultimately is just design choice that the creators made.

---

> I don't know why Scala couldn't get away with just having function objects.

Because, originally, in **Scala 2** methods are more powerful than functions.

For example, functions can't have type parameters, can't receive `implicit` values, can't be overloaded, etc.

**Scala 3** created a bunch of features to reduce those limitations like context functions *(`A ?=> B`)* and type lambdas *(`[X] =>> F[X]`)*. But methods still have some unique things like overloading.

Additionally, due to how the **JVM** works, you need methods anyway. Since at the end of the day a **function** is just an **object / value** with an `apply` **method** attached to it.

There are also performance arguments, since if we only had **functions** then there would be a lot of indirections, to ultimately having to call a **method** at runtime.

---

Having said all that, in theory, the language could have abstracted all those internal details, just have functions, make functions special, and the compiler could inline most things to methods in classes and all that.

However, there could have been a lot of reasons for not doing that. I don't know the real ones, but I can imagine some plausible ones like:

- The generated code could be slower and wasteful.
- Extra work for the compiler. Both in the sense it would be slower, and harder to maintain.
- Harder interop with other **JVM** languages like **Java** *(this alone was a big no-no on early **Scala** days when there were not so many native libraries)*.

Answer (score 0):

There are no "functions" in JVM, only methods. A function in scala is just an instance of a trait, like

```
trait Function1[In, Out] {
   def apply(in: In): Out
}
```

Now, why the compiler refuses to convert a method to a function in your example - that's just because someone with power in scala community felt that it shouldn't. I don't think there is a rational reason for it, and it's definitely not because of any JVM limitation. (I may be wrong, but I think earlier versions of scala used to allow these conversions, it was only removed later).

Comment: You've got it backwards: in Scala 2, you had to write `val g = f _`, but in Scala 3 you can simply write `val g = f`.

Comment: @SethTisue yeah, I know that. But, though, like I said, I could be wrong on this, but I seem to remember, that is _used to_ be possible in earlier versions of scala 2, but then was taken away (thus the awkwardly verbose error message basically telling you that it knows exactly what you want to do, but still requiring you to spell it out).

Comment: Well, hmm, it would have to be a realllllllllllly ancient version of Scala, as Scala 2 has been this way at least since Scala 2.7, which came out in 2008. Not sure about versions before that.